# where is it the database when embedding neo4j in java servlet applications?

Tags: servlets, neo4j

I'm new to neo4j and to web java programming.
I'm trying to use neo4j in a servlet application and for performance reasons I prefer to java-embed it rather than using the REST APIs.

The question is: ok, if I use REST then there will be a service listening on a certain porta that manages all the database stuff and execute my query and I'm ok, like mysql and other services. But what's the meaning of "embed" it ? where is the database manager? is it all in the jars?

second question. What is the "database path" I'm specifying when I load databases? is it a logical path that the database uses or it is a real path in which db data will be saved?

last one: I'm thinking to put the database creation in init() method so as to load it once per same-prcess-threads and I put the shutdown in destroy() for the same reason. am i doing correctly?

But on the website I've read that no two instances pointing to the same database can exist at same time. But what for two servlets sharing the same database? I start servlet A and it load database DB and then I start B and what happens?

Answer (score 0):

I think if you are new to Neo4j and Java (Web) programming, you should start with the server and graph modeling.

Stick to Cypher and use it via one of the drivers. Eg. the JDBC driver.

After you have acquainted yourself with Neo4j, Cypher your graph data model etc. and only if you run into performance issues you can look into writing an unmanaged server extension for those use-cases.

Comment: thanks very much for replying. Why should I? what's wrong with start using it embedded?

Comment: If you are new to Java programming and graph databases it makes sense to learn one thing first and then the other, not both at once.

Comment: Ah ok in that sense! I'm not new to java, only to the web-side of it. Anyway I'm getting familiar with neo4j and I really like it so I want to understand it independently to which way I use it. That's the reason of the questions

Comment: I still would stick to cypher it makes it easier to use both embedded and remotely.